# Pdo sqlite driver issue

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, pdo

I'm just beginning laravel and when i try to return articles JSON from sqlite, i get this driver error.

```
public function index(){
    $articles = \App\Article::all();
    return $articles;
}
```

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 PDOException in Connector.php line 55: could not find driver

```
in Connector.php line 55
at PDO->__construct('sqlite:/srv/http/laravel/storage/database.sqlite', null, null, array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in Connector.php line 55
at Connector->createConnection('sqlite:/srv/http/laravel/storage/database.sqlite', array('driver' => 'sqlite', 'database' => '/srv/http/laravel/storage/database.sqlite', 'prefix' => '', 'name' => 'sqlite'), array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in SQLiteConnector.php line 37
at SQLiteConnector->connect(array('driver' => 'sqlite', 'database' => '/srv/http/laravel/storage/database.sqlite', 'prefix' => '', 'name' => 'sqlite')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 60
at ConnectionFactory->createSingleConnection(array('driver' => 'sqlite', 'database' => '/srv/http/laravel/storage/database.sqlite', 'prefix' => '', 'name' => 'sqlite')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 49
at ConnectionFactory->make(array('driver' => 'sqlite', 'database' => '/srv/http/laravel/storage/database.sqlite', 'prefix' => ''), 'sqlite') in DatabaseManager.php line 175
at DatabaseManager->makeConnection('sqlite') in DatabaseManager.php line 67
at DatabaseManager->connection(null) in Model.php line 3245
at Model::resolveConnection(null) in Model.php line 3211
at Model->getConnection() in Model.php line 1914
at Model->newBaseQueryBuilder() in Model.php line 1857
at Model->newQueryWithoutScopes() in Model.php line 1831
at Model->newQuery() in Model.php line 667
at Model::all() in ArticlesController.php line 14
at ArticlesController->index()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ArticlesController), 'index'), array()) in Controller.php line 256
at Controller->callAction('index', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 164
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(ArticlesController), object(Route), 'index') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 112
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 114
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(ArticlesController), object(Route), object(Request), 'index') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 69
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController', 'index') in Route.php line 201
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 704
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 706
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 671
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 631
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42`enter code here`
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('/srv/http/laravel/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Comment: Can you check if `pdo_mysql` extension is enabled? To verify it's enabled, use `phpinfo()` . `php -i` command is not enough because PHP CLI using different configuration settings.

Comment: Can you share you phpinfo() output ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8S2BJY9DhjAQjF5T0o3VXNMVG8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, I was meaning `pdo_sqlite` but typed `pdo_mysql`  accidentally. `pdo_sqlite` seems enabled, i'm looking for solving problem. Just give me a few minutes :)

Comment: thanks, btw I'm using archlinux, i seem to have all packages installed. idk what can the problem be

Comment: Let's check everything from beginning. You should have these packages `sqlite`, `php5-sqlite` . And built with pecl. `pecl install pdo && pecl install pdo_sqlite` . Lastly you should enable pdo, pdo_sqlite extensions in your php.ini . You did all of them right?

Comment: eloquent seems to work

Comment: yes, i did all those things

Comment: But there is no `pdo_sqlite` section in your phpinfo() output. Maybe it's not enabled. Don't forget this .ini file loaded : `/etc/php/php.ini`

Comment: also my .env file (idk maybe this is the issue)
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=sdafkljsakldf


DB_CONNECTION=sqlite

Comment: pdo_sqlite is uncommented :O extension=pdo_sqlite.so

Comment: Check this folder for pdo_sqlite.so file **/usr/lib/php/modules/** . Also `php -v` will output if are there any missing extension files.

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
 here it is

Comment: ohh no i pasted it in php.ini it could be just a random error sorry

Comment: whatever, i might just use vagrant then...

Comment: So i'll send it as an answer so if someone come from Google , can find answer. Accept it please :)

Answer (score 1):

Please be sure you've installed`pdo` and `pdo_sqlite` extensions properly.

`php -v` will output if are there any missing extension files.

You should have these packages `sqlite`, `php5-sqlite` . And built with pecl. `pecl install pdo && pecl install pdo_sqlite` . Lastly you should enable pdo, pdo_sqlite extensions in your php.ini. According to your phpinfo() output, your php.ini file is `/etc/php/php.ini`

And again according to your phpinfo() output, your extension folder is `/usr/lib/php/modules/` . There should be `pdo_sqlite.so` file in this directory.

Answer (score -1):

I found out that if we can write to the database, then the connection is working fine. We all faced the issue when trying to retrieve from database. I resolved this issue by restarting the server. That worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on again" is fine as [an IT Crowd gag](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8) but not a satisfactory answer on StackOverflow.